# In which Voyager episode did the ship go to warp despite having sustained damage?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

Most of Star Trek: Voyager has become a mercifully dim memory to me, but there was one moment that's really stuck with me.  I'd like to know what episode it was from.

What I recall is this:

The ship is attacked, presumably by a more powerful enemy, because Janeway orders the ship to escape into warp.  The friends I was watching the episode with and I exchanged knowing comments to the effect that it would never work, since it seemed to be a pretty common Star Trek trope that any attack on a ship--however slight--would knock out the warp drive and force the crew to deal with the situation at hand.

But in THIS case, the camera cut away to an exterior view of the ship tumbling through space.  If I recall correctly, the camera is even rotating at a different rate than the ship, maybe even in the opposite direction, creating an impression of vertigo.  And as the ship tumbles, the warp nacelles lock into position, and...BOOM, it warps away.  My friends and I just stared, dumbfounded.  Some of us might even have cheered after the shock wore off.

So...which episode was that scene in?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might be referring to the Voyager's episode [Scorpion S03E26](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion_(episode)) in which:

> On the bridge, Paris reports that the alien ship is detaching and
>   powering up, apparently readying to fire a weapon. Kes, who is also on
>   the bridge, experiences another vision of the pilot on that bio-ship
>   communicating with her. Janeway orders Paris to take them out of the
>   area at maximum warp. **As Voyager moves away, the bio-ship fires, not
>   landing a direct hit but Voyager loses control. Paris is able to jump
>   to warp speed, and the bio-ship does not give chase.**

From [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/voy068.txt):

> JANEWAY: Get us out of here-maximum warp!
>
> Paris works...
>
> 78 EXT. SPACE-VOYAGER (OPTICAL) as it turns away from the Borg
>   graveyard... the alien BIO-SHIP SENDS OUT a CRACKLING TENDRIL of
>   ENERGY, whip-like, powerful, the same effect seen in the Teaser.
>
> The tendril narrowly MISSES Voyager, but even so SENDS our ship
>   SPINNING WILDLY!
>
> 79 INT. BRIDGE Red Alert. SHAKING! Everyone hanging on! Paris working
>   frantically...
>
> 80 EXT. SPACE-VOYAGER (OPTICAL) as it STOPS its tailspin and JUMPS
>   into WARP!

You can see it here too:

Comment: Ah, that's the stuff!  Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't really 'damage' so much as [poor attitude control/upset ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_upset)

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps this was [Year of Hell, Part 1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell_(episode))? At one point Voyager is attacked by the Krenim Weapon Ship, which is certainly a "more powerful enemy" considering its ability to erase its targets from space-time. Voyager is forced to use warp to escape despite being heavily damaged. They do successfully escape, but the stress of travelling at warp speeds causes huge chunks of the hull to tear away.

[image: Voyager with sections of hull missing]

I'm trying to find video footage to see if there's any of the camera rotation you mention.

Edit: having found the episode and re-watched the scene I mentioned I don't think this was actually the episode you were thinking of. There's no shot of the ship going to warp, just the shot above of the hull peeling off. I'll keep looking.

Comment: It should be noted that in this situation, they didn't really want to go to warp, due to the integrity forcefields being compromised as well.   They knew they would incur heavy damage but decided that surviving and going into warp was the only option.